# How to find square root number in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

Is there any algorithm or code to find square root of integer in VHDL? The code must not contain these library:

```
IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
IEEE.math_real.all;
IEEE.std_logic_signed.all;
IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
```

Comment: [Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) ... *4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.* Consider taking the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: On the other hand this question would likely not be off-topic at [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vhdl).

Answer (score 2):

See [VHDL samples](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/samples/samples.shtml#sqrt32)
...
**32-bit parallel integer square root**

The VHDL source code is [sqrt32.vhdl](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/samples/sqrt32.vhdl)
    The output of the VHDL simulation is [sqrt32.out](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/samples/sqrt32.out)
    The schematic was never drawn. sqrt8m.vhdl was expanded
    using "generate" statements to create sqrt32.vhdl

Only contains references to package ieee.std_logic_1164, accepts a std_logic_vector length 32 and returns a length 16.

Amazing what you can find googling with search terms ***square root VHDL*** .

**Addendum**

I got curious and a testbench for sqrt32.vhdl is small. There's an error in the code, it's not functional. The apparent way to correct it would be to re-implement it. It likely suffers from an erroneous assumption in expanding sqrt8m.vhdl mentioned as the source (which could also be validated).

There are other square root VHDL models available. Sequential (successive subtraction divider) models are not uncommon in books on VHDL arithmetic, with the various implementations of division (e.g. non-restoring).

There's also a square root function in -2008 IEEE package float_pkg which is synthesis eligible and has the dynamic range for a 32 bit integer in the mantissa of a 64 bit floating point number. It's not one of the proscribed packages and the package has the necessary conversion routines.

Answer (score 0):

Appears you are looking for synthesizable code, and in that case the question should mention that.

Some mathematical operations are usually supported by the synthesis tools, like integer addition (`a + b`), integer negation (`- a`), integer subtraction (`a - b`), integer multiplication (`*`), while other mathematical operations are not, like point square root operation.

So a synthesizable square root operation must be implemented separately, like suggested by user1155120, and the implementation will depend on requirements to arguments, accuracy, throughput, latency, size, etc.

But for simulation purpose, and not synthesizable, you can use `ieee.math_real.sqrt`, with an example below that prints the square root value for `2.0`:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.math_real.all;
...
report real'image(sqrt(2.0)) severity NOTE;
```

Comment: Why not use `ieee.math_real` if in test bench (non-synthesizable) code?  And for synthesizable design, see my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

If the literal wording is that the code cannot contain `IEEE.math_real.all;` you can circumvent the problem by selecting only what you need from math_real.

Then `IEEE.math_real.sqrt;` will do what you want.

However while this satisfies the letter of the question asked above, I cannot guarantee it satisfies the intent.

A better answer would be to take ANY algorithm for computing square root - there are many, easily found in the usual sources. Implement it in VHDL, and test it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution based on Mr. Crenshaw's algorithm:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity SQRT is
    Generic ( b  : natural range 4 to 32 := 16 ); 
    Port ( value  : in   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           result : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end SQRT;

architecture Behave of SQRT is
begin
   process (value)
   variable vop  : unsigned(b-1 downto 0);  
   variable vres : unsigned(b-1 downto 0);  
   variable vone : unsigned(b-1 downto 0);  
   begin
      vone := to_unsigned(2**(b-2),b);
      vop  := unsigned(value);
      vres := (others=>'0'); 
      while (vone /= 0) loop
         if (vop >= vres+vone) then
            vop   := vop - (vres+vone);
            vres  := vres/2 + vone;
         else
            vres  := vres/2;
         end if;
         vone := vone/4;
      end loop;
      result <= std_logic_vector(vres(result'range));
   end process;
end;
```